# Printing Simple Pattern in Python

Tags: python

I would like to print the following pattern in Python

input: 5

output:

```
    5
   456
  34567
 2345678
123456789
```

I have used the following code but it is not showing the above pattern. Anyone help me on this topic, please?

CODE:

```
rows = int(input("Enter number of rows: "))

k = 0
count=0
count1=0

for i in range(1, rows+1):
    for space in range(1, (rows-i)+1):
        print("  ", end="")
        count+=1

    while k!=((2*i)-1):
        if count<=rows-1:
            print(i+k, end=" ")
            count+=1
        else:
            count1+=1
            print(i+k-(2*count1), end=" ")
        k += 1

    count1 = count = k = 0
    print()
```

OUTPUT:

```
        1
      2 3 2
    3 4 5 4 3
  4 5 6 7 6 5 4
5 6 7 8 9 8 7 6 5
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you just want a pattern starting from n and going to 1 in decreasing order left side, and starting from n and going to 2n-1 in increasing order right side

```
  def pattern(n):
        for i in range(n,0,-1):
            for j in range(1,i):
                print(" ",end="")
            for k in range(i,2*n-i+1):
                print(k,end="")
            print()

pattern(5)

    5
   456
  34567
 2345678
123456789
```